# Create new folder in 'images' with every new article

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I need to extend standard Joomla article options.
I want to create new folder for article's images in 'images/news/' folder. The name for every new folder will be taken from article's alias.
I'm have knowledge in Javascript, but have no idea how can I do this with PHP and wich files I need edit for this. My website works on Joomla 2.5 and at this moment I can't update it. So please keep in mind this moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge in Joomla. But this is the php command for creating a Folder:

```
 $dirPath = 'images/news/'.$alias;
 $result = mkdir($dirPath);
```

Ok like I said, i don't really know joomla. But it doesn't look that hard:
https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_content_plugin
So i will try to give you a start. But if there is an answer from somebody who is skilled in Joomla i would listen to them =)

Basically you Need 2 Files for your Content plugin. A php File "myContentPlugin.php" which will look like this:

```
<?php

 defined('_JEXEC') or die();

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');


class plgMyComponent extends JPlugin
{
 public function __construct($subject, $config)
 { parent::__construct($subject, $config);
 }

 function onContentBeforeSave($context, &$article, $isNew)
 { global $mainframe;


 $dirPath = 'images/news/'.$articel->alias;
 $result = mkdir($dirPath);

 return true;
 }
}
```

and an XML file "myContentPlugin.xml" which will look like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <extension version="1.7" type="plugin" group="content">
    <name>myContentPlugin</name>
    <author>JD</author>
    <creationDate>September 2011</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2011 JD. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
    <authorEmail>me@mail.de</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.domain.de</authorUrl>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
    <description></description>
    <files>
            <filename plugin="myContentPlugin">myContentPlugin.php</filename>
    </files>
```

As found from here http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2607024

Comment: Thank you for tryin' help me! Ofcource I'd found mkdir function in PHP documentation, but I don't know how to apply it when I save my article.

Comment: what exactly you don't know ? when to triggger it ? onContentAfterSave could do the trick.

Comment: Yes. I don't know where I need place function wich create folder.

Comment: i think you will Need either onContentBeforeSave or onContentAfterSave! Look at this:
https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content

Comment: Like I said, unfortunatelly I'm new in PHP, and can't write plugin with ContentAfterSave option. But anyway thank you :)

Comment: I started write my own plugin to resolve this issue. I have some success, but at this moment I can't gat parameters from article anyway... I'll try to learn more.

Comment: So here is my try to write my own plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162049/how-to-get-parameters-from-articles-custom-field Now I can get any parameter from article, so I believe soon here will be full solution for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is complete solution:

Add custom field type checkbox to article's backend (you can find many manuals over the inernet, so I'll be brief), for example 'create_folder';

```
<fieldset name="image_folder" label="Image folder">
    <field name="create_folder"
        type="checkbox"
        label="Create automatically"
        value="1"
        default="0"
        filter="intval"
    />
</fieldset>
```

Create plugin folder with .xml and .php files of your plugin (more info here: https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla )

This is code of my .php file:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class plgContentImgDir extends JPlugin
{
        public function onContentAfterSave($context,&$article){ 
        if($context=='com_content.article'){     
                $folder_name=substr($article->alias,0,30);
                $destination=JPATH_SITE.'/'."images/news";
                if(!file_exists($destination.$folder_name)){       
                    JFolder::create($destination.'/'.$folder_name,0755);
                }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

After you install your plugin, you'll get additional option in your article settings. If checkbox checked the new folder will be create in 'images' directory.