# How to get parameters from article's custom field?

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I have some custom field for artciles. For example this is text field named "MyText".

I tryin' to write simple plugin, wich will be display text from this field on article's page (frontend). So how can I get value from this field and transfer it to plugin?

Joomla version is 2.5

Thanks in advance for everybody.

This is field in XML:

```
<field name="MyText" type="inputbox"
            label="MyText"
            description=""
            class="inputbox" size="25"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Finally I wrote it by myself. So here is solution:

```
 public function onContentAfterDisplay($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
{
    $articleId = (JRequest::getVar('option')==='com_content' && JRequest::getVar('view')==='article')? JRequest::getInt('id') : 0;
    $article =& JTable::getInstance('content');
    $article->load($articleId);

    $art_attribs = new JParameter($article->attribs);
    $mytext = $art_attribs->get('MyText');

    echo $mytext;
}
```

Comment: I'm new in PHP so I believe my code is not perfect. But I can explain what I doin' here.: at first I get ID of  article, where plugin's text will be. After I got ID or existing article I create new parameter $art_attribs to get it's value. So nothing difficult here.